# Magento Certified Professional Cloud Developer Exam Reading Material

Tags: magento2, certification, cloud, magento2-cloud

Recently Magento announced  **Certified Professional Cloud Developer** exam for Magento2.

> https://u.magento.com/magento-certified-professional-cloud-developer

I have some questions about this **Certified Professional Cloud Developer** exam.

- What is the passing score for magento cloud developer exam?
- Which study materials useful for preparation of this exam except **Free study Guide**?
- What is the retake policy for this exam?
- How many free retakes are available?
- What is difference between professional and cloud certification?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions

- 62% or higher needed to pass
- As of now they only have [course designed](https://u.magento.com/magento-commerce-cloud-for-developers) , but you can always refer to [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/bk-cloud.html)
- Retake policy is almost the same for all exams ,4 attempts
- There are no retakes , they used to give out coupons in December(couple of years back) which allows you for a free retake . Now they just give out 20% discount coupon
- It would have more Cloud (Magento Cloud) centric questions , Professional developer is based Magento CE and Developer plus is based on Magento EE

Answer (score 0):

I have passed the Magento Cloud Developer exam recently. Question can not be remember as they are in multi line and hard to understand. The main point is question understanding. If you understand the question correctly, you get the answer.

You can check my profile below:

https://u.magento.com/certification/directory/dev/2345554/

1. I have developed 1 starter project.
2. I have read through SwiftOtter guide 2 times
3. And cloud dev docs 2 times

No free retakes available. But you will get some discount on second attempt, Please go thru Magento certification portal for more details.

Commerce Cloud Fundamentals 13% 
Local Environment   9% 
Cloud Configuration   13% 
Service Configuration    5% 
Deployment Process 10% 
Static Content Deployment  10% 
Development   20% 
Troubleshooting   10%
Go Live and Maintenance  10%

Good luck.